# Layout two controls in one row so that the right one is always fully visible in SWT

Tags: layout, swt

A UI with a label on the left and a button-like `Link` widget on the right, both in one *row*, should be layouted so that the `Link` is never cropped.

[image]

If there is enough space, the controls should be left-aligned:

[image]

If not enough space, the label should be decreased in width (thereby cropping its content) so that the link is still fully visible:

[image]

The snippet below does what it should. However, it uses a `RowLayout` and a resize listener to adjust the `RowData` to assign abolute width to the particular control. This contradicts the whole idea of using a layout manger.

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );

  Composite container = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
  Label label = new Label( container, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( "kdsajf alkdsjf sadkf dsakfjalksd fadskjf sadlk sfdk dsflkjg" );
  Link link = new Link( container, SWT.NONE );
  link.setText( "<a>Do Something...</a>" );

  RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
  layout.marginWidth = 0;
  layout.wrap = false;
  container.setLayout( layout );
  label.setLayoutData( new RowData() );
  link.setLayoutData( new RowData( 90, SWT.DEFAULT ) );
  container.addListener( SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
      int linkWidth = link.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT ).x;
      RowData rowData = ( RowData )link.getLayoutData();
      rowData.width = linkWidth;
      rowData = ( RowData )label.getLayoutData();
      rowData.width = container.getClientArea().width - linkWidth - ( layout.spacing * 2 );
      if( label.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT ).x < rowData.width ) {
        rowData.width = SWT.DEFAULT;
      }
    }
  } );

  shell.pack();
  shell.open();
  while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

My hope is that there is a simpler solution, possibly using a regular SWT layout.